# Chunking in DocBook 5 limits TOC depth and makes it skip numbers?

Tags: xml, xslt, tableofcontents, docbook-5, docbook-xsl

I have a DocBook V5.0 document that used to be one `.docbook` file containing the entire book.  At that point, the generated TOC looked fine.  Now, I have chunked the input into 4 different `.docbook` files and also want chunked output.

After this change I suddenly have two problems:

1. The TOC **only contains four entries** (one for each .docbook) rather than the full depth it used to
2. Quite oddly, the TOC chapter numbers are **1, 2, and 4, then the glossary,** which doesn't have a number.

About the latter, if I remove the second chapter, I get 1, 2, and the glossary, so I guess it's nothing about the second chapter's content that causes the misnumbering.

Anyway, my question is, how do I restore a normal-looking TOC while retaining chunked input and output?  (The chunking could even be limited to single-file depth, i.e., one file in, one file out--but I want the TOC depth much higher.)

### What I did

I made my main file look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE book [
    <!ENTITY a SYSTEM "a.docbook">
    <!ENTITY b SYSTEM "b.docbook">
    <!ENTITY c SYSTEM "c.docbook">
    <!ENTITY glossary SYSTEM "glossary.docbook">
    <!ENTITY larr "&#x2190;">
    <!ENTITY rarr "&#x2192;">
    <!ENTITY mdash "&#x2014;">
]>
<book xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<title>My Title</title>
&a;
&b;
&c;
&glossary;
</book>
```

My XSL is similar to before with the addition of a handful of chunking control options (but no changes to the original TOC option):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet  
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:import href="/usr/share/sgml/docbook/xsl-stylesheets/html/chunk.xsl"/>

<xsl:output method="html"
            encoding="UTF-8"
            indent="no"/>
<!--new--><xsl:param name="chunk.quietly" select="1"></xsl:param>
<!--new--><xsl:param name="chunker.output.encoding">UTF-8</xsl:param>
<!--new--><xsl:param name="html.extra.head.links" select="0"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="html.stylesheet" select="'main.css'"/>
<xsl:param name="generate.toc">
  book      toc,title
</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="glossentry.show.acronym">yes</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="glossary.sort" select="1"></xsl:param>
<!--new--><xsl:param name="use.id.as.filename" select="1"></xsl:param>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My `.docbook` files all look like this:

A
    ...

Except `glossary.doc` which is:

Glossary

Now, I realize it may be a bit strange having a chapter within a chapter.  This may even be the cause.  However, it validates without warning, and also, if I make the outermost tag in a given file `<section>` instead, then the entire file is missing from the TOC.

Answer (score 2):

**TIP:** Replace the older `<!ENTITY  ...>` with [xinclude](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/). This has the advantage that all can be nice validated by xml schema's. Also XML editors can better away with xinclude, then with the file inclusion through `ENTITY`.

Below is an example:

File: `book.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<book version="5.0" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
      xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
  <info>
    <title>This is a book</title>
  </info>

  <chapter>
    <title>This is a chapter</title>

    <section>
      <title>This is a section</title>

      <para>This is a paragraph.</para>
    </section>

    <xi:include href="included_section.xml" />
  </chapter>
</book>
```

File: `include_section.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<section version="5.0" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
         xmlns:ns5="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
         xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
  <title>This is an included section</title>
  <para>This is an included paragraph.</para>

  <mediaobject>
    <imageobject>
      <imagedata fileref="media/martin-luther-king.jpg"></imagedata>
    </imageobject>
  </mediaobject>
</section>
```

In this example there is also an directory `media` containing the file `martin-luther-king.jpg`.

Your example above would look like:

```
<book version="5.0" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
      xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
    <title>My Title</title>
    <xi:include href="chapter-a.xml" />
    <xi:include href="chapter-b.xml" />
    <xi:include href="chapter-c.xml" />
    <xi:include href="glossary.xml" />
</book>
```

And each separate *chapter* file, could look like:

```
<chapter version="5.0" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
      xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
    <title>This is a chapter</title>

    <section>
      <title>This is a section</title>

      <para>This is a paragraph.</para>
    </section>
</chapter>
```

And the *glossary* file, could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<glossary version="5.0" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" 
        xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>Example Glossary</title>

    <para>
        This is not a real glossary, it's just an example.
    </para>
</glossary>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but isn't one of the nice things about using DocBook V5.0 that you can call your file `.docbook` and leave off the `<?xml...` and docbook namespaces?  In any case, your syntax did work, but the result was the same (TOC numbering 1, 2, and 4, then glossary; and TOC not going beyond that depth either.)  Nonetheless +1 because I learned something trying it this way and appreciate your thoroughness.

Comment: Ok thx for explaining, I was not awere if DocBook extension. Regarding the issue almost sounds there is some issue with the content or improved XSL. Can you share a small example of those content files? Maybe a GitHub Gist https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/

Comment: Thanks, looking into the content files was key to solving the problem.  Answered below.

Answer (score 0):

Do not nest chapters within the included `.docbook` files.  Use `chapter` for the outermost tag and `section` for everything within.

(Despite validation, I discovered that the shortest file, which I tried to restructure by changing its outermost tag to `chapter` and then its inner `chapter` tag to `section`, actually had a missing pair of `chapter` tags, so it had had a chapter with two `titles` and so on.  Before noticing this, this had been causing it not to show up on the TOC, so I had assumed that I had proven that `section`-within-`chapter` didn't work for some reason, when actually it was these missing tags from my cut-n-paste job.  Don't rely on the validator!)